# How to use The MetadataType Attribute in a library targeting .net standard 1.4

Tags: c#, metadata, data-annotations, .net-standard-1.4

I created a library targeting the .net standard 1.4.  The library contains my domain model (POCOs). I want to decorate my classes with  the MetadataType and the dataannotations attributes. I installed the System.ComponentModel.Annotations but the MetaDataTypeAttribute is absent. I tried to install the Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc package but is not compatible with .net standard 1.4.
Can any body tell me, how can i do to inherit the dataAnnotations defined in my interfaces in a library targeting .net standard 1.4 ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`MetadataTypeAttribute` - along with `BindableTypeAttribute` and `ScaffoldTableAttribute` - is not part of any version of .NET Standard (<= 2.0) and also not available on .NET Core so you cannot currently use it in a .NET Standard project and you cannot load a .NET Framework library into .NET Core 2.0 that uses it.

See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16101) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22469) GitHub issues for details.

Comment: I am converting my libraries to .Net Standard 2.0.  I have a library that defines a DB table. It has lost the sizing constrains by moving to .Net Standard. I am including the library in a 4.7.2 web app. From the above links it seems that the issue was resolved in Dec 2018. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure, you may be hitting something else (e.g. missing binding redirects). I suggest creating a project to reproduce your issue (web app + .net standard library) and opening a new question or filing an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/standard